# readValue and readTree in Jackson: when to use which?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm just starting using the Jackson JSON library. Jackson is a very powerful library, but it has a terribly extensive API. A lot of things can be done in multiple ways. This makes it hard to find your way in Jackson - how to know what is the correct/best way of doing things?

Why would I use this solution:

```
String json = "{\"a\":2, \"b\":\"a string\", \"c\": [6.7, 6, 5.6, 8.0]}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readValue(json, JsonNode.class);
if (node.isObject()) {
    ObjectNode obj = mapper.convertValue(node, ObjectNode.class);
    if (obj.has("a")) {
        System.out.println("a=" + obj.get("a").asDouble());
    }
}
```

Over a solution like this:

```
String json = "{\"a\":2, \"b\":\"a string\", \"c\": [6.7, 6, 5.6, 8.0]}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(json);
if (node.isObject()) {
    ObjectNode obj = (ObjectNode) node;
    if (obj.has("a")) {
        System.out.println("a=" + obj.get("a").asDouble());
    }
}
```

Or over solutions that I came across using JsonFactory and JsonParser and maybe even more options...

It seems to mee that mapper.readValue is most generic and can be used in a lot of cases: read to JsonNode, ObjectNode, ArrayNode, PoJo, etc. So why would I want to use mapper.readTree?

And what is the best way to convert a JsonNode to an ObjectNode? Just cast to ObjectNode? Or use something like mapper.convertValue?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

readValue() can be used for any and all types, including `JsonNode`. readTree() only works for `JsonNode` (tree model); and is added for convenience.

Note that you NEVER want to use your first example: it is equivalent to writing out your node as JSON, then reading it back -- just cast it.

Comment: thanks, this is useful information. I assumed that convertValue was smart enough to just cast to the correct type when possible and that it would be safer than casting myself...

Comment: That's an interesting idea -- maybe such code could be added? Name 'convert' is meant to convey conversion; not simply cast, but I guess it's not unreasonable expectation. I'll file an improvement issue for this.

Answer (score 14):

Read value can be used for your own java classes:

```
public class Foo {
   private int a;
   private String b;
   private double[] c;

   // getters/setters
}

String json = "{\"a\":2, \"b\":\"a string\", \"c\": [6.7, 6, 5.6, 8.0]}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Foo foo = mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class);
```

i.e. You may choose `readTree` when you do not know exact type of the Object, and `readValue` when you know the Object type for sure.

Comment: Indeed, that is one of the things that makes readValue usable in amore situations than readTree, so why ever choose readTree over readValue?

Comment: readTree you may choose when you do not no exact type of the object. while readValue - when you know the object type for sure.

Answer (score 2):

These methods have different **runtime** when you are parsing (deserializing, unmarshalling) same JSON.

The **fastest** way is using **readValue()** with **type reference HashMap**:

```
TypeReference<HashMap<String, Object>> typeRef= new TypeReference<>() {};

HashMap<String, Object> parsedJson = objectMapper.readValue(json,typeRef);
```

Using **readTree**() and writing manual parser with JsonNode objects also wiil give you **fast runtime**.

Additional benefit of using **readTree**(): you can use **stream parallel** when parsing ArrayNode objects, which will boost runtime on multicore processors.

On the other hand, you can use **Jackson Streaming API** (JsonParser class) to get similar runtime as **stream parallel**.

The **slowest** way is using **readValue()** with **POJO** class:

```
YourPOJO parsedJson = objectMapper.readValue(json, YourPOJO.class);
```

Finally, you can combine **readValue()** with **POJO** and **Jackson Streaming API** to get a good runtime.

Here is a cool example how to use Jackson Streaming API for both the cases: [Jackson Streaming API](https://cassiomolin.com/2019/08/19/combining-jackson-streaming-api-with-objectmapper-for-parsing-json/).

This is approximate runtime of each parsing (deserializing, unmarshalling) way on same JSON:

```
Auto parsing raw map with ObjectMapper readValue() runtime: 34 ms
Auto parsing type reference map with ObjectMapper readValue() runtime: 6 ms
Auto parsing POJO with ObjectMapper readValue() runtime: 51 ms
Manual sequential parsing with ObjectMapper readTree() runtime: 18 ms
Manual stream parallel parsing with ObjectMapper readTree() runtime: 10 ms
Jackson Streaming API manual parsing with JsonParser runtime: 8 ms
Jackson Streaming API combining ObjectMapper readTree() runtime: 14 ms
```

I have done my example and tests here:

> https://github.com/EvgenyUmansky/java-json-xml-processing/blob/master/src/test/java/JacksonTest.java

Another tests here:

> https://gist.github.com/varren/3b7468a1d7abadad4958fe6bd7d42d44