# Jackson deserialization convertValue vs readValue

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a org.json.JSONArray that contains JSONObjects and I am trying to map those to a POJO. I know the type of the POJO I want to map to. I have 2 options and I m trying to figure out which is better in performance.

Option 1:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectReader reader = mapper.reader().withType(MyPojo.class);

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
    MyPojo pojo = reader.readValue(obj.toString());

    ... other code dealing with pojo...
}
```

Option 2:

```
ObjectReader mapper = new ObjectMapper();

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject obj = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
    MyPojo pojo = mapper.convertvalue(obj, MyPojo.class);

    ... other code dealing with pojo...
}
```

For sake of argument, lets assume the length of the JSONArray is 100.

From what I have looked so far from the source code, option 1 seems better since the Deserialization context and the Deserializer is created only once, while in case of option 2, it will be done for each call.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Please fix your second code snippet so that it compiles. I want it to be clear what you are asking about.

Comment: Please update this post with your findings so that it helps others.

Comment: I have the same dubt as you. I found this on stackOverFlow, might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113512/readvalue-and-readtree-in-jackson-when-to-use-which

Comment: Second snippet could lead to errors as internal structure of `org.json.JSONObject` is not the same as that of a JSON.

Answer (score 6):

I will try to explain the difference, with the problem I faced. I used both in a complex conversion I needed to use.

My request was of the format as below.

```
"{Key=a1, type=ABC}"
```

I wanted to convert it to some class's (A1) instance.

```
class A1 {
   private String key;
   private String type;
}
```

As is clear, the keys are not strings (i.e. not enclosed in double quotes)

**With mapper.readValue**

I will get error as below:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('k' (code 115)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
```

**With mapper.convertValue**

I will get an instance of A1 as I required.

Comment: You mean your input was not json?

Comment: Yes. It was an object representation.

Answer (score 4):

Its simple

- For converting json string to class type use readValue
- For converting object type to class type use convertValue

On printing, object looks like this
SampleClass(id=61, applicationReference=AP251, accountId=fghsdjffhhjf)

On printing, jsonString a looks like this
{"method":"POST","url": "xyz.com"}